# How to make label show up on contour vector in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, contour

I'm new to QGIS (version 2.6.0). I think my question should be easy to solve but I still get stuck at making labels show up on contour lines. These lines were generated from extracting raster (asc file). Then I tried to label those contour lines on the plot. I checked the box of "label this layer with XX" (XX is the attribute name I need) in layer properties, and clicked OK, but the there is no label showing up, I also changed the front size, but still I can't see any label. Is there anything else I need to do to make it work?

Comment: What happens if you zoom in to look at a single line - still no label visible? Do you have any 'scale based visibility' options checked ('Rendering')?

Comment: I zoomed in but there is still no label visible. The 'scale based visibilty' option is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled QGIS version 2.6.1. Now the problem is solved.